# Deploy to Azure with a normal IP

Tags: azure

I followed [these instructions](http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2011/05/15/Step-by-step-instructions-to-deploy-ASPNET-MVC-3-to-Windows-Azure.aspx) to deploy to Azure:

And it actually worked, but I get a Guid for a Website URL.  How can I hook it up to an Azure website?  Something like patrickinmpls.azure.com ?

[image: Guid IP]

Comment: You deployed to staging. Staging always uses a randomly generated URL, since it's only meant to be used temporarily, and not affect your production instance. Inside the Azure console, you can swap your instances. This lets you test your new deployment, and if something goes wrong after the swap, change back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @mfanto's comment, you would need to publish your application to production slot and then you'll get a **yourservicename.cloudapp.net** URL which you can then map to your custom domain name. See this link for more details: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/.